# Upload file to Google Drive via API

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Everyone
I need to upload file to Google Drive via the API, I did exactly what it is mention https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php.

I had generated the access token and saved it in the file, the problem is that it only works for the first time and next time it gives error

```
OAuth2 token, message: '{ "error" : "invalid_grant" }
```

We only need to upload files to Google drive (our own account) after getting from the users by form.

I had tried scripts from many tutorial but it didn't seem to work.
I had also tried with offline access permission but still no luck.

**Update:**
Here it the code that I use to generate access token

```
require_once APP_PATH.'_includes/google_drive/Google_Client.php';
require_once APP_PATH.'_includes/google_drive/contrib/Google_DriveService.php';

$drive = new Google_Client();

$drive->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$drive->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$drive->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');

$drive->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$gdrive = new Google_DriveService($drive);

$url = $drive->createAuthUrl();
$authorizationCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

$token = $drive->authenticate($authorizationCode);
```

And then I used this code
        $drive = new Google_Client();

```
$drive->setClientId('xxxxxxxxxxx');
$drive->setClientSecret('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$drive->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
$drive->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

$gdrive = new Google_DriveService($drive);

$_GET['code']= '4/axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

file_put_contents('token.json', $drive->authenticate());

$drive->setAccessToken(file_get_contents('token.json'));

$doc = new Google_DriveFile();

$doc->setTitle('Test Document');
$doc->setDescription('Test description');
$doc->setMimeType('text/plain');

$content = file_get_contents('document.txt');

$output = $gdrive->files->insert($doc, array(
      'data' => $content,
      'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
    ));
print_r($output);
```

it works good and but when I run the page again it says

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Google_AuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant'' in ...Google_OAuth2.php on line 115
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `$client->authenticate($authCode);` again. Please clarify what you're doing with a snippet.

Comment: @BurcuDogan I had updated the question, i had done exactly as mentioned in this tutorial http://www.html.it/articoli/google-drive-e-php-come-integrarli/

Comment: thanks @BurcuDogan, it works after removing the authenticate method.

Comment: What is this line doing? I am getting error on this line `$authorizationCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));` Use of undefined constant STDIN - assumed 'STDIN' can you explain the STDIN?

Comment: What is STDIN? it looks it is NOT defined yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @BurcuDogan's comment, commenting out authenticate method resolved the issue.

```
//file_put_contents('token.json', $drive->authenticate());
```